# Sticky Header/Footer With 3 columns. Divs that scroll within the columns

Tags: css

I have a JS Fiddle here.

https://jsfiddle.net/h3c6jqfy/

Basically, i am trying to make a UI that has a sticky header and footer. The middle content will have three columns. Each columns will have DIVs in them. These DIVs should have 100% height and not be cut off from the footer. Within the DIV, they will have scrollable divs.

[image]

The very basic layout I created has this in it...

```
d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>this is the end!!
```

The part where it says this is the end!! is never reached.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox **without** the need to calculate heights;

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 75px;
  background: red;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
}

.scrolly {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <div class="scrolly">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="scrolly">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scrolly">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: can i ask why calculating heights may not be the best?

Comment: I didn't say it's not the *best*, it's just not *necessary* - Flexbox doesn't need to know the heights of the header/footer to create this layout. In addition, the CSS doesn't need updating if those values change.

Comment: Nor is all that absolute positioning required which is *inflexible* by it's very nature.

Comment: I agree, my solution is quick for the markup you had but its definitely not the best option since you can use flexbox to stretch, align and justify you flex-items with few lines of code; avoiding specifying too many heights, widths, etc

Comment: By setting heights and widths in too many elements it can become really hard to keep track of everything in the long run and tiny changes can break a lot. @DroiDev consider reading this guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: See Fiddle in Full Screen**

You can try using flexbox instead of defining every unit, calculate the height to avoid using the space where the footer sits, and let the children div inherit its height

```html
<style>
body, head {overflow: hidden;}
#header,#footer,#content { position:absolute; right:0;left:0;}

#header{
   height:100px; top:0; background: #4A4A4A;

}
#footer{
  height:100px; bottom:0; background: #4A4A4A;
}
#content{
  top:100px;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  background:#fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

</style>

<div>
<div id="header">HEADER</div>
<div id="content">
  

      <div style="background-color: #ff0000; min-width: 33%; height: inherit; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div style="background-color: blue;min-height: inherit;max-width: 99%;padding: 20px 40px;">
          <div style="overflow: auto; max-height: inherit; padding: 10px;">
       <br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d
    <br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>
                d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>
                d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br><br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>
                d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>
                d<br>d<br>d
                <br>d<br>this is the end!!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div style="background-color: #ff0000; min-height: 100%; min-width: 33%; max-width: 33%;float: left;">
        <div style="background-color: red;min-height: 100%;max-width: 99%;padding: 20px 40px;">
          middle
        </div>
      </div>

      <div style="background-color: #ff0000; min-height: 100%; min-width: 33%; max-width: 33%;float: left;">
        <div style="background-color: pink;min-height: 100%;max-width: 99%;padding: 20px 40px;">
          right
        </div>
      </div>
     
</div>
<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```